# Logo's link only partially functional

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, graphical-logo

I am currently using two files: test.html and style.css and the logo is only partially functioning as a link. Is there any way I can fix this?

A preview of the problem can be seen here: [Website Test](http://www.mindtale.com/test.html)

test.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
<title>Mindtale</title>
</head>


<body>

<div id="headerlogo">
<a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
</div>


<div id="headerlink1">
<a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
</div>


<div id="headerlink2">
<a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</div>



<div id="headerimg"></div>

<div id="content1">
</div>



<div id="footer">
Mindtale &copy; 2013
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
html { 
height:100%; /* fix height to 100% for IE */
max-height:100%; /* fix height for other browsers */
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}


div#headerlogo {
z-index:0;
position:fixed;
left: 41%;
top: 24px;
}


div#headerlink1 {
z-index:2;
position:fixed;
top:50px;
left:18%;
width:100%;
color:#999;
padding: 0px;
}

div#headerlink2 {
z-index:3;
position:fixed;
top:50px;
left:78%;
width:100%;
color:#999;
padding: 0px;
}


div#headerimg {
position:fixed;
background: url(images/header.png) no-repeat center;
height: 102px;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
padding: 0px;
}


div#content1 {
position:fixed;
width:100%;
color:#222;
top: 70px; 
bottom: 0; 
left: 0; 
right: 0;
padding: 25px;
overflow: auto;
}


div#footer {
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
color:#999;
background:#333;
padding: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Specify please what you mean with "partially working". I realize we can go to the website an test, but improve your question by making clear exactly what the error is and what you want it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#headerlogo a {
   display: block;
}
```

And remove the `width:100%;` from the headerLink divs because they are overlaying your logo.

Answer (score 1):

Your `headerlink1` div is partially *over* the logo.

This makes that bit of the logo unclickable.

How to fix? Change the design - perhaps two divs for the different links - something that will not obscure the logo.